# Why does the order of statements in an 'or' condition matter?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I was working through a problem where I was reversing words in place. I noticed that depending on the order of my statements before and after my `or` operator, the code would not work or work.

If I change

```
if i == len(s1) or s1[i] == ' ':
```

to

```
if s1[i] == ' ' or i == len(s1):
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reverse_words_in_place.py", line 58, in <module>
    reverse_words(s1)
  File "reverse_words_in_place.py", line 6, in reverse_words
    if s1[i] == ' ' or i == len(s1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```py
def reverse_words(s1):
    reverse_string(s1, 0, len(s1)-1)

    start_index = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)+1):
        if i == len(s1) or s1[i] == ' ':
            reverse_string(s1, start_index, i-1)
            start_index = i + 1
    return s1


def reverse_string(s1, first, last):
    while(first < last):
        s1[first], s1[last] = s1[last], s1[first]

        first += 1
        last -= 1

s1 = ['c', 'a', 'k', 'e', ' ',
      'p', 'o', 'u', 'n', 'd', ' ',
      's', 't', 'e', 'a', 'l']

reverse_words(s1)

# Prints: 'steal pound cake'
print(''.join(s1))
```

The output for this code is

```
steal pound cake
```

as long as

```
if i == len(s1) or s1[i] == ' ':
```

Why does it matter in what order these statements are?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in python, as in most programming languages, the operators **or** and **and** short circuit.  For example, if the left hand side of **or** is true, then it knows the *entire* **or** statement will be true without bothering to check the right hand side.

**Long winded explanation:**

It *may seem* like to evaluate **A or B** we would start by evaluating **A**, then we'd evaluate **B** and finally the results would be **or**'d together for the final result.  However, what *actually* happens is the "short circuit": **A** is evaluated and, if it is true, we don't bother evaluating **B** *AT ALL* because we know *right then and there* that **A or B** evaluates to true.

Similarly, **A and B** short circuits: we start by evaluating **A** and if it is false we already know that **A and B** will evaluate to false, so we don't bother evaluating **B** at all.

This can *actually* be used to write more succinct code.  For example, the following:

```
if A: # is obj valid?
  if B: # do a check that requires obj to be valid
    C
```

...could be written like this instead:

```
if A and B:
  C
```

Answer (score 8):

Because if `i == len(s1)` is `true` the second statement is not evaluated and you don't get `IndexError`.

The reason for it is [Short-circuit_evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

OR stops looking for condition as soon as it finds true.